# How could I give pad to this antenna section?

Tags: pcb, antenna, pad

I have a SC20 schematic diagram.

From the diagram, there is an antenna section as shown.

How can I give a pad to this antenna for drawing PCB in EasyEDA?

The schematic provided some information like 1.55MM, but I could not understand.

[image]

Comment: How would you give pads to L103 - how does the information shown on the schematic tell you what pad sizes and shape to use?

Comment: other antenna section in schematic specify that UFL connector ,but this antenna tuner section only gives this specific information.so that doubt regarding antenna connector